# nothing showing up at UV Editing

Tags: texturing

So basically, i made a sword in roblox studio, but when you convert a model into a mesh it doesn't carry on the texure. So what I'm trying to do is get the texture as a png by using blender.

I already saw someone ask how to do this on here, and it was answered that you have to go to UV Editing and then Image and save it. But the problem is nothing shows up in UV Editing.

I'm really bad at blender but I have no idea why it isn't showing up.

Also it looks nothing like its supposed to in blender, for some reason the hilt is red

[image]

Comment: You are in *Object mode*. press `tab` to go into *Edit mode*. Press `A` to select everything. If you still don't see anything in the UV editor then that means you have no UV map. Press `u` *> unwrap* to create a new UV map.

Comment: Additional to what @HarryMcKenzie says: you cannot tab into _Edit Mode_ like that, the sword is red because you have selected **all** objects in your scene and the sword is **not** the active one (it would have a brighter orange outline). The other objects selected are the camera and the light, and you can't switch to editing on any of those. So simply left-click on the sword, this makes it the only object selected and automatically the active one. Or to make sure nothing else is selected, press Alt+A first to deselect all, then click on the sword. Now you can do the steps Harry described.

Comment: By the way - you can see in the _Outliner_ window that none of the selected objects has a brighter orange. This means, none of them is an active object, this is usually caused by having deleted an object (which was the active one) and then - without selecting a new one by clicking on it and making it the active one - pressing A to select all. Now there is no active object and even if all of them were editabel mesh objects, _Tab_ to switch into _Edit Mode_ would not work and even the mode selection in the menu doesn't show any options to change the mode.

Comment: Hey, It kind of worked, but for some reason it comes out as this weird purple texture, anyone know why?

Here's the image: https://imgur.com/a/sUXUAga

Comment: You just need to delete the Texture, the texture name is above the UV Editor, just cllick the "X" icon